# Magento 1.9 - How to rewrite magento cms page to custom url with query parameter

Tags: magento-1.9, url-rewrite

I want to rewrite CMS page url to custom url.

For eg. CMS page url is `"/result/?q=test"` and rewrite url should be `"/demo/test"`

For this I'm trying to below htaccess rule

```
RewriteRule ^demo/?$ /result/?q=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Url `"/result/?q=test"` is working, but the url `"/demo/test"` is showing 404 not found.

What rule should I use this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually all request redirected to the index.php which internally uses $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] to determine what page or resource actually requested.
Above htaccess will just redirect the request to /result/ but to index.php $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] will remain /demo/test

What you can do is add below code to your index.php it will do the trick

```
if(strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],'/demo/')!==FALSE)
{
   $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] = '/result/?q='.str_replace('/demo/', '', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
}
```